# i can not use intent to another activity, every time i have null, where problem?

Tags: kotlin, android-intent

`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0WqZ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4SIc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd2Rr.png)

in AuthActivity im create userLogin, after if we can auth, im send in BasketActivity my login, i wanna do my nickname in basket of shop. But every time i took null, if i dont use toString(), im take nothing.

who can help me?`

Comment: look my images, thx

Answer (score 0):

You are Intent with BusketActivity then again Intent with ItemActivity. I think, here is the problem.
[image]